# Receiving extended data with ssh using twisted.conch as client

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, twisted.conch

I'm currently in the process of learning ssh via the brute-force/ just keep hacking until I understand it approach.  After some trial and error I've been able to successfully send a "pty-req" followed by a "shell" request, I can get the login preamble, send commands and receive stdout but I'm not exactly sure how to tell the SSH service I want to recieve stderr and status messages.  Reading through other SSH implementations ( paramiko, Net::SSH ) hasn't been much of a guide at the moment.

That said, looking at one of the RFC's for SSH, I believe that perhaps one of the listed requests might be what I am looking for: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4250#section-4.9.3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from twisted.conch.ssh import transport
from twisted.conch.ssh import userauth
from twisted.conch.ssh import connection
from twisted.conch.ssh import common
from twisted.conch.ssh.common import NS
from twisted.conch.ssh import keys
from twisted.conch.ssh import channel
from twisted.conch.ssh import session
from twisted.internet import defer

from twisted.internet import defer, protocol, reactor
from twisted.python import log
import struct, sys, getpass, os
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)


USER = 'dward'  
HOST = '192.168.0.19' # pristine.local
PASSWD = "password"
PRIVATE_KEY = "~/id_rsa"

class SimpleTransport(transport.SSHClientTransport):
    def verifyHostKey(self, hostKey, fingerprint):
        print 'host key fingerprint: %s' % fingerprint
        return defer.succeed(1) 

    def connectionSecure(self):
        self.requestService(
            SimpleUserAuth(USER,
                SimpleConnection()))

class SimpleUserAuth(userauth.SSHUserAuthClient):
    def getPassword(self):
        return defer.succeed(PASSWD)

    def getGenericAnswers(self, name, instruction, questions):
        print name
        print instruction
        answers = []
        for prompt, echo in questions:
            if echo:
                answer = raw_input(prompt)
            else:
                answer = getpass.getpass(prompt)
            answers.append(answer)
        return defer.succeed(answers)
            
    def getPublicKey(self):
        path = os.path.expanduser(PRIVATE_KEY) 
        # this works with rsa too
        # just change the name here and in getPrivateKey
        if not os.path.exists(path) or self.lastPublicKey:
            # the file doesn't exist, or we've tried a public key
            return
        return keys.Key.fromFile(filename=path+'.pub').blob()

    def getPrivateKey(self):
        path = os.path.expanduser(PRIVATE_KEY)
        return defer.succeed(keys.Key.fromFile(path).keyObject)
        
    
    
class SimpleConnection(connection.SSHConnection):
    def serviceStarted(self):
        self.openChannel(SmartChannel(2**16, 2**15, self))        




class SmartChannel(channel.SSHChannel):
    name = "session"
    
    
    def getResponse(self, timeout = 10):
        self.onData = defer.Deferred()
        self.timeout = reactor.callLater( timeout, self.onData.errback, Exception("Timeout") )
        return self.onData
    
    def openFailed(self, reason):
        print "Failed", reason
        
    @defer.inlineCallbacks    
    def channelOpen(self, ignoredData):
        self.data = ''
        self.oldData = ''
        self.onData = None
        self.timeout = None
        term = os.environ.get('TERM', 'xterm')
        #winsz = fcntl.ioctl(fd, tty.TIOCGWINSZ, '12345678')
        winSize = (25,80,0,0) #struct.unpack('4H', winsz)
        ptyReqData = session.packRequest_pty_req(term, winSize, '')
        
        try:
            result = yield self.conn.sendRequest(self, 'pty-req', ptyReqData, wantReply = 1 )
        except Exception as e:
            print "Failed with ", e
        
        try:
            result = yield self.conn.sendRequest(self, "shell", '', wantReply = 1)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Failed shell with ", e
        
        
        #fetch preample    
        data = yield self.getResponse()
        """
        Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-server x86_64)

            * Documentation:  http://www.ubuntu.com/server/doc
           
             System information as of Sat Oct 29 13:09:50 MDT 2011
           
             System load:  0.0               Processes:           111
             Usage of /:   48.0% of 6.62GB   Users logged in:     1
             Memory usage: 39%               IP address for eth1: 192.168.0.19
             Swap usage:   3%
           
             Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/
           New release 'oneiric' available.
           Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
           
           Last login: Sat Oct 29 01:23:16 2011 from 192.168.0.17
        """
        print data
        while data != "" and data.strip().endswith("~$") == False:
            try:
                data = yield self.getResponse()
                print repr(data)
                """
                \x1B]0;dward@pristine: ~\x07dward@pristine:~$ 
                """
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                break
                
        self.write("false\n")
        #fetch response
        try:
            data = yield self.getResponse()
        except Exception as e:
            print "Failed to catch response?", e
        else:
            print data
            """
                false
                \x1B]0;dward@pristine: ~\x07dward@pristine:~$ 
            """
            
        self.write("true\n")
        #fetch response
        try:
            data = yield self.getResponse()
        except Exception as e:
            print "Failed to catch response?", e
        else:
            print data
            """
            true
            \x1B]0;dward@pristine: ~\x07dward@pristine:~$ 
            """
        
        self.write("echo Hello World\n\x00")
        try:
            data = yield self.getResponse()
        except Exception as e:
            print "Failed to catch response?", e
        else:            
            print data
            """
            echo Hello World
            Hello World
            \x1B]0;dward@pristine: ~\x07dward@pristine:~$ 
            """
        
        #Close up shop
        self.loseConnection()
        dbgp = 1
        
    
    def request_exit_status(self, data):
        status = struct.unpack('>L', data)[0]
        print 'status was: %s' % status    
    
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data += data
        if self.onData is not None:
            if self.timeout and self.timeout.active():
                self.timeout.cancel()
            if self.onData.called == False:                
                self.onData.callback(data)
    
    def extReceived(self, dataType, data):
        dbgp = 1
        print "Extended Data recieved! dataType = %s , data = %s " % ( dataType, data, )
        self.extendData = data

    def closed(self):
        print 'got data : %s' % self.data.replace("\\r\\n","\r\n")
        self.loseConnection()
        reactor.stop()
        
    

protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, SimpleTransport).connectTCP(HOST, 22)
reactor.run()
```

Additionally I tried adding in an explicit bad command to the remote shell:

```
    self.write("ls -alF badPathHere\n\x00")
    try:
        data = yield self.getResponse()
    except Exception as e:
        print "Failed to catch response?", e
    else:            
        print data
        """
        ls -alF badPathHere
        ls: cannot access badPathHere: No such file or directory
        \x1B]0;dward@pristine: ~\x07dward@pristine:~$ 
        """
```

And it looks like stderr is being mixed into stderr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through the source code for OpenSSH, channel session logic is handled in [session.c](http://anoncvs.mindrot.org/index.cgi/openssh/session.c?view=markup) at line 
2227 function -> session_input_channel_req  which if given a pty-req then a "shell" request leads to do_exec_pty which ultimately leads to the call to session_set_fds(s, ptyfd, fdout, -1, 1, 1).  The forth argument would normally be a file descriptor responsible for handling stderr but since none is supplied then there won't be any extended data for stderr.

Ultimately, even if I modified openssh to provide a stderr FD, the problem resides with the shell.  Complete guess work at this point but I believe that similar to logging into a ssh service via a terminal like xterm or putty, that stderr and stdout are sent together unless explicitly redirected via something like "2> someFile" which is beyond the scope of a SSH service provider.

Comment: If you're requesting a PTY, it makes sense that stderr and stdout would go to the same place: you can think of the pseudo-TTY itself as like "the screen", and you obviously want to send stdout and stderr both to somewhere that the user can see them.  Have you looked at what happens with an `exec` request rather than a `pty-req` request?

Comment: There's a branch where exec splits on do_exec_pty and do_exec_no_pty, without a PTY stderr is captured.  In my tests it's only shell that doesn't provide a returnval for execution which makes a lot of sense.